# is there any way to pass spring profiles to debug a spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

below is the command i am using to run a spring boot application by adding the profiles but i am unable to run spring boot application in debug mode from eclipse/sts , is there any way we can specify profiles in sts/eclipse and run application in debug mode ?

mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=seed,create,dev1,dbH2  : from command prompt

AND from eclipse/sts i am using project->Debug As->Debug configuration , in Goals I am passing below command

spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=seed,create,dev1,dbH2

Answer (score 1):

you can add -Dspring.profiles.active={profiles} to VM argument in the Eclipse as below

1. click on Debug configuration
2. click on Argument tab
3. add -Dspring.profiles.active=seed,create,dev1,dbH2 to Vm argument

Comment: in my case I had to add it in Environment variable not sure why, but it actually worked after I add it in environment variables input box.

Answer (score 1):

I am using latest intelij idea and a maven project. to run the project with local profile, I had to add it in environment variable section of edit build configuration window.
PFA the image.
[image: Edit Run/Debug configuration]